# maxscript get class properties at onece

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I have a problem in getting all properties of material from scene or material editor.

```
v = meditMaterials[1]
showProperties v
```

But this only shows me what properties has VrayMtl class (in my case). 
Is there a way to get all the properties of the class with baked in values. In my case a material in material editor slot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of, though in this case you're not missing all that much - it's only *name*, *effectsChannel* and *showInViewport* (Material superclass) and *category*, *classID* and *superClassID* (MAXWrapper super-superclass). You can find them under [Material Common Properties, Operators, and Methods](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-23A6A316-7C51-430C-8A44-9236C837DB10.htm) and [MAXWrapper Common Properties, Operators, and Methods](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-95453E22-A022-4543-B31C-A052CECD3598.htm).